# CMD rename files if has certain prefix, works if ALL files have (or don't have) prefix, fails if even one if different

Tags: file, loops, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I'm making a .BAT script for people who use POPStarter on modded PlayStation 2s.

Using that requires a `.ELF` file to have one of four formats (depending on how game will be loaded.)

1. `XX.somegame.ELF` is for loading from USB
2. `PP.somegame.ELf` is for loading from a per game partition on PS2s HDD
3. `__.somegame.ELF` is for loading from a hidden per game partition on PS2s HDD
4. `somegame.ELF` is for loading from a `__.POPS` partition on PS2s HDD

This script should rename the files to be used in the corresponding format.

I have my code to where if all `.ELF` files have a prefix (doesn't matter which of the three) or if they ALL lack the prefix, the command runs perfectly, HOWEVER if there is even one file that is different (all have prefix, one doesn't, or all lack prefix, one has) ALL files are treated like the differing file.

my code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Mode con: cols=115 lines=40
color 17
set "logfile=ELF_Test_Log.txt"
Set "Replace1=XX"
Set "Replace2=__"
Set "Replace3=PP"
SET "_prefix=%1:~0,3%"
goto start
:1
set load=
set/a loadnum=0
if Not Exist "*.ELF" goto Loading1b
:Loading1a
set load=%load%[0]
cls
echo.
echo Processing... Please Wait...
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo %load% 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==20 goto done1
goto Loading1a
:done1
cls
echo.
echo Processing Complete!
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu
:Loading1b
cls
echo %date% - %time%  No ELF files >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
echo.
echo.
echo There are currently NO .ELF files to Rename
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu

:2
set load=
set/a loadnum=0
if Not Exist "*.ELF" goto Loading2b
:Loading2a
set load=%load%[0]
cls
echo.
echo Processing... Please Wait...
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo %load% 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==20 goto done2
goto Loading2a
:done2
cls
echo.
echo Processing Complete!
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu
:Loading2b
cls
echo %date% - %time%  No ELF files >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
echo.
echo.
echo There are currently NO .ELF files to Rename
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu

:3
set load=
set/a loadnum=0
if Not Exist "*.ELF" goto Loading3b
:Loading3a
set load=%load%[0]
cls
echo.
echo Processing... Please Wait...
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo %load% 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==20 goto done3
goto Loading3a
:done3
cls
echo.
echo Processing Complete!
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu
:Loading3b
echo %date% - %time%  No ELF files >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo There are currently NO .ELF files to Rename
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu

:4
set load=
set/a loadnum=0
if Not Exist "*.ELF" goto Loading4b
:Loading4a
set load=%load%[0]
cls
echo.
echo Processing... Please Wait...
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo %load% 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
set/a loadnum=%loadnum% +1
if %loadnum%==20 goto done4
goto Loading4a
:done4
cls
echo.
echo Processing Complete!
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][] 
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu
:Loading4b
echo %date% - %time%  No ELF files >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo There are currently NO .ELF files to Rename
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause
goto menu
:start
echo %date% - %time% Start Program >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
echo Welcome to renaming Utility
pause
goto menu
:menu
echo %date% - %time% Menu Loaded >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
cls
echo [1] USB formated       [2] Hidden Partition(individual)
echo [3] OLD HDD Method     [4] NEW HDD Method
echo.
echo [X] Exit
CHOICE /C 1234X
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 goto exit
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 goto loading4
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 goto loading3
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto loading2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto loading1
:loading1
echo %date% - %time% - Checking If File has Prefix >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%~na
set F=!F:~3!
if %%a == %Replace1%.!F!%%~xa goto 1b else
if %%a == %Replace2%.!F!%%~xa goto 1b else
if %%a == %Replace3%.!F!%%~xa goto 1b else goto 1a
)
:1a
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has no Prefix, Adding %Replace1%. >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
ren "%%a" "%Replace1%.%%a" >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
)
pause
goto 1
:1b
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%a
set F=!F:~3!
echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has a prefix, renaming to %Replace1%.!F! >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
ren "%%~a" "%Replace1%.!F!" >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
)
goto 1
:loading2
echo %date% - %time% Checking If File has Prefix >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%~na
set F=!F:~3!
if %%a == %Replace1%.!F!%%~xa goto 2b else
if %%a == %Replace2%.!F!%%~xa goto 2b else
if %%a == %Replace3%.!F!%%~xa goto 2b else goto 2a
)
:2a
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') do (
set F=%%a
echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has no Prefix, Adding %Replace2%. >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
ren "%%a" "%Replace2%.%%a" >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
goto 2
:2b
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%a
set F=!F:~3!
echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has a prefix, renaming to %Replace2%.!F! >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
ren "%%~a" "%Replace2%.!F!" >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
)
goto 2
:loading3
echo %date% - %time% - Checking If File has Prefix >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%~na
set F=!F:~3!
if %%a == %Replace1%.!F!%%~xa goto 3b else
if %%a == %Replace2%.!F!%%~xa goto 3b else
if %%a == %Replace3%.!F!%%~xa goto 3b else goto 3a
)
:3a
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') do (
set F=%%a
echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has no Prefix, Adding %Replace3%. >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
ren "%%a" "%Replace3%.%%a" >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
goto 3
:3b
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%a
set F=!F:~3!
echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has a prefix, renaming to %Replace3%.!F! >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
ren "%%~a" "%Replace3%.!F!" >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
)
goto 3
:loading4
echo %date% - %time% - Checking If File has Prefix >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%~na
set F=!F:~3!
if %%a == %Replace1%.!F!%%~xa goto 4b else
if %%a == %Replace2%.!F!%%~xa goto 4b else
if %%a == %Replace3%.!F!%%~xa goto 4b else goto 4a
)
:4a
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has no Prefix, Should Work with NEW HDD install type >> "%logfile%" 2>&1)
pause
goto menu
:4b
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') Do (
set F=%%a
set F=!F:~3!
echo %date% - %time% - File %%a has a Prefix, Now removing it >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
ren "%%a" "!F!" >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
)
goto 4
:exit
cls
echo %date% - %time% End Program >> "%logfile%" 2>&1
pause
exit
```

The `:loading` part is there four times (corresponding to the 4 desired outcomes)

Using two files, this is the log read out for when they have the same structure

```
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:19:03.56 Start Program 
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:19:05.08 Menu Loaded 
Checking If File has Prefix 
File C_C[CD1].elf has no Prefix, Adding XX. 
File C_C[CD2].elf has no Prefix, Adding XX. 
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:19:07.84 Menu Loaded 
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:19:12.62 End Program
```

and this is the log output for when all are `somegame.ELF` and just one is `XX.somegome.ELF`:

```
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:28:17.38 Start Program 
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:28:18.83 Menu Loaded 
Checking If File has Prefix 
File C_C[CD1].elf has a prefix, renaming to XX.[CD1].elf 
File XX.C_C[CD2].elf has a prefix, renaming to XX.C_C[CD2].elf 
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:28:21.02 Menu Loaded 
Sun 09/20/2015 - 14:28:22.37 End Program
```

How can I fix this last missing part?

EDIT- added full BAT Script .....

Comment: What's the `goto 1`? You do not have any `:1` label in the batch file.

Comment: @martin-prikryl as I said it is a snippet of the pertinent info.  :1 is a loading bar animation that goes back to menu when  finished

Comment: It would be _very_ helpful to clean up your code before you post it here; there are tons of `echo`s that don't contribute anything to the question but blow up the post extensively...

Comment: The first time it was a SNIPPET that contained only the relevant code, was asked about other parts, so I posted entire code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really tell us what your script should be doing.

But I assume the problem is that you actually test only the first file. The first `for` loop does actually never loop. It just inspects the first file it gets and jumps to respective "action" loop.

You want to test each an every file and act accordingly. You need just one `for` loop for that:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.elf') do (

    set F=%%~na
    set F=!F:~3!
    set ADD=1
    if %%a == %Replace1%.!F!%%~xa set ADD=0
    if %%a == %Replace2%.!F!%%~xa set ADD=0
    if %%a == %Replace3%.!F!%%~xa set ADD=0

    if !ADD! == 1 (

        echo File %%a has no Prefix, Adding %Replace1%. 
        ren "%%a" "%Replace1%.%%a"
        pause

    ) else (

        set F=%%a
        set F=!F:~3!
        echo File %%a has a prefix, renaming to %Replace1%.!F! 
        ren "%%~a" "%Replace1%.!F!"

    )
)
```

Comment: sorry, I though I did specify that.   my mistake. after making choice on a menu, should then either rename a file with PP, XX, or __ prefix to have another of those prefixes (based on selection), Add the prefix(if file didn't have one) or remove the prefix (if required for the last of the four types)

Comment: OK, well we won't write the code for you. I believe my answer showed you the way. Now, it's up to you.